# Size of UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I make sure my `UIViewRepresentable` has the same width as it's parent? I have created a representable class for a `UILabel` with an attributed text (converted from HTML).

`AttributedLabel.swift`:

```
struct AttributedLabel: UIViewRepresentable {

    let attributedText: NSAttributedString

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.attributedText = attributedText
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {}

}
```

Usage example:

```
List {
    VStack {
        AttributedLabel(attributedText: attributedText)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The question is incorrect. Containers in SwiftUI do not have own size, until you specify it explicitly with `.frame`, and forward size calculations to content, ie. children, ie in your case to `AttributedLabel`.

Comment: OK, then how do I make the contained view respect the bounds of the parent view? In autolayout I would constrain the left and right side of the view to the parent to make sure it doesn't grow beyond the width of the parent.